# Compare UUID timestamps in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, timestamp, uuid

In python how can I compare the timestamps of different UUIDs e.g **960a1a9e-1753-11ea-a653-e4b97af3ed7b** and **a33ba868-1753-11ea-87df-e4b97af3ed7b** that have been created using:

```
from uuid import uuid1

my_uuid = str(uuid1())
```

I want to know which one was created first.

If I use this site I can see the exact date and time it was created: https://www.famkruithof.net/uuid/uuidgen

Answer (score 2):

You can get the timestamps from the UUIDs like this:

```
from uuid import UUID

id1 = UUID('960a1a9e-1753-11ea-a653-e4b97af3ed7b')
id2 = UUID('a33ba868-1753-11ea-87df-e4b97af3ed7b')
print(id1.time)
print(id2.time)
```

The documentation outlines this here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID.fields

> time | the 60-bit timestamp